# Stretch flex to height but scroll inner content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't find anything that works for my issue.

I have a flex container and two fixed width left and right columns and the expandable content in the middle. I need the middle content to get its own vertical scroll bar when there is too much, but it currently only works horizontally.

https://jsfiddle.net/pLerox7f/

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div class="full-container">
            <div id="col1">
                hello
            </div>

            <div id="col2">
                <div>
                    this content scrolls horizontally correctly but not vertically
                </div>
                <div>
                     <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div>
                    other content
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="col3">
                right content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.full-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 32px);
}

.footer{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}

#col1 {
    background-color: darkgray;
    flex: 0 0 230px;
}

#col2 {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 4px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#col3 {
    background-color: dimgray;
    flex: 0 0 230px;
}
```

In this example if you make the window height smaller it pushes the footer down instead of making a scroll bar.

Any fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change your `min-height` of  **full-container**   to `height` and everything works as you wanted

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.full-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 32px);
}

.footer{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}

#col1 {
    background-color: darkgray;
    flex: 0 0 230px;
}

#col2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 4px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#col3 {
    background-color: dimgray;
    flex: 0 0 230px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div class="full-container">
            <div id="col1">
                hello
            </div>

            <div id="col2">
                <div>
                    this content scrolls horizontally correctly but not vertically
                </div>
                <div>
                     <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div>
                    other content
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="col3">
                right content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```